# Calculating average build duration in Teamcity for failure condition improvements

Tags: sonarqube, teamcity, metrics, build-rules

Nice to have following functions for failure condition in TeamCity. But, I would like to have the average building time for each project or each submodule to be able to use it as a threshold value. I have limited plugin options since what I use is enterprise version.

Option 1: Having statistics for building time weekly, monthly, etc and calculating avg manually to be able to benefit it as I want.

Option 2: Using SonarQube as a server, adding meta runner and adding it to build steps. But, I am not sure if I can have this value on Sonar.

Question 1: Do you have any possible solution idea for that? I want to have my custom metric in a logical/shortest way. (Based on teamcity documentation, it is possible.)

Question 2: Is Option2 possible? What do you think?

Thank you!

Teamcity: 2022.10 - Enterprise
SonarQube: 9.9.1 - Enterprise

·       last successful build

·       last pinned build

·       last finished build

·       build with specified build number

·       last finished build with specified tag.